# why two logins for ssh?

Tags: password, ssh

I've created `test` account on my `Mac` for testing purposes. It originally worked with no issues, but now it is asking for a second password. Here is what I'm talking about:

```
$ ssh test@localhost
Password:
test@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Does anybody know what is going on? It used to simply say `Password`, now it also added `test@localhosts's password:`. Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

Output of `ssh -vvv test@localhost`

```
someuser-mbp:src someuser$ ssh -vvv test@localhost
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 4: Applying options for *
debug2: checking match for 'host *.facebook.com,dev,dev*' host localhost originally localhost
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 7: not matched 'host "localhost"'
debug2: match not found
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'test'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/someuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/someuser/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:5
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:8
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:11
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:14
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:17
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:20
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:23
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 8 keys from localhost
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EkNdCUWw9b6lXdoUjERVdB/JddJXPblBUSffq75Bb4o
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/someuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/someuser/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:2
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:5
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:8
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:11
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:14
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:17
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:20
debug3: record_hostkey: found ca key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:23
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 8 keys from localhost
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/someuser/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/someuser/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
test@localhost's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/7 cc -1)

Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
Connection to localhost closed.
Transferred: sent 2032, received 1724 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5055056.8, received 4288837.5
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Comment: Post the verbose log from the `ssh -vvv test@localhost`

Comment: @Jakuje Just added the otuput

Comment: These are two different authentication methods `password` and `keyboard-interactive`. But I can't tell you why the server is asking for both of them. It sounds like a misconfiguration.

Comment: @Jakuje hmm...how would I configure it to work properly? I don't deal with `ssh` on a regular basis.

Comment: You should find the server configuration in `sshd_config`, probably under `/etc/ssh`, but I do not deal with Mac on regular basis.

Comment: Are you using an ssh key (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)? Because that first password prompt is a local one, probably to unlock the cert.

Comment: @ToddDabney I don't think so. How would I know?